# Array help needed for unit conversion application

Tags: vb.net

I have a project to do in Visual Basic. 
My problem is that the outcome is always wrong (ex. instead of 2011 it gives 2000). And i cannot set as Desired unit the Inch(1) or feet(3), it gives the Infinity error. And if i put as Original and Desired unit the inch(1), the outcome is "Not a Number".

Here's the code i made so far. The project is about arrays. Any help appreciated.

> Public Class Form1
>
> ```
> Private Sub btnConvert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
>
>     Dim original(9) As Long
>     Dim desired(9) As Long
>     Dim a As Integer
>     Dim o As Integer
>     Dim d As Integer
>     Dim inch As Long, fathom As Long, furlong As Long, kilometer As Long
>     Dim meter As Long, miles As Long, rod As Long, yard As Long, feet As Long
>
>     a = Val(Input3.Text)
>     o = Val(Input1.Text)
>     d = Val(Input2.Text)
>
>     inch& = 0.0833
>     rod& = 16.5
>     yard& = 3
>     furlong& = 660
>     meter& = 3.28155
>     kilometer& = 3281.5
>     fathom& = 6
>     miles& = 5280
>
>     original(1) = inch
>     original(2) = fathom
>     original(3) = feet
>     original(4) = furlong
>     original(5) = kilometer
>     original(6) = meter
>     original(7) = miles
>     original(8) = rod
>     original(9) = yard
>
>     desired(1) = inch
>     desired(2) = fathom
>     desired(3) = feet
>     desired(4) = furlong
>     desired(5) = kilometer
>     desired(6) = meter
>     desired(7) = miles
>     desired(8) = rod
>     desired(9) = yard
>
>     If o < 1 Or o > 9 Or d < 1 Or d > 9 Then
>         MessageBox.Show("Units must range from 1-9.", "Error", _
>         MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
>         MessageBoxIcon.Information)
>         Return
>     End If
>
>     Output.Text = (a * original(o)) / desired(d)
>
> End Sub
> ```
>
> End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geia sou Manoli,

usually arrays are zero based.
Also inch, meters etc should be declared as double, not long.

This code will do the convertion corectly

```
    Private Sub btnConvert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim original(8) As Double
    Dim desired(8) As Double
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim o As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim inch As Double, fathom As Long, furlong As Double, kilometer As Double
    Dim meter As Double, miles As Long, rod As Double, yard As Double, feet As Long

    a = CInt(Val(Input3.Text))
    o = CInt(Val(Input1.Text))
    d = CInt(Val(Input2.Text))

    inch = 0.0833333333
    rod = 16.5
    yard = 3
    furlong = 660
    meter = 3.2808399
    kilometer = 3280.8399
    fathom = 6
    miles = 5280

    original(0) = inch
    original(1) = fathom
    original(2) = feet
    original(3) = furlong
    original(4) = kilometer
    original(5) = meter
    original(6) = miles
    original(7) = rod
    original(8) = yard

    desired(0) = inch
    desired(1) = fathom
    desired(2) = feet
    desired(3) = furlong
    desired(4) = kilometer
    desired(5) = meter
    desired(6) = miles
    desired(7) = rod
    desired(8) = yard

    If o < 0 Or o > 8 Or d < 0 Or d > 8 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Units must range from 0-8.", "Error", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Return
    End If

    Output.Text = CStr((a * original(o)) / desired(d))

End Sub
```

Comment: Also you can only use the original array. The desired array is not needed.

For example: 
Output.Text = CStr((a * original(o)) / original(d))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply!

Now it works perfectly.

I was about to ask about another problem, but i figured it out.

> Output.Text = CStr((a * original(o)) / desired(d))

has to be converted to

> Output.Text = CStr((a * original(o - 1)) / desired(d - 1))

Euxaristw!